# samsung series 5 A6 ultrabook

Tags: ati, 64-bit

i'm a fan of ubuntu, but for now i want my installation to be perfect for my new laptop, its a series 5 of samsung with A6 processor.

Somebody suggest what to do? or mention any problems related to this? 
Im more concern of the drivers to increase its performance because i am to develop an android app.
I need "i dont know" to make this unit run as fast as possible without any dangerous tradeoffs.
Also i read some forum saying that their units are overheating. -_- 
somebody help me please. 
and also i want to switch to gnome 3. And last thing, is there any differences in performance if i use alongside, replace or custom in formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can use live CD/DVD/USB to try Ubuntu on your Samsung series 5 A6 Ultrabook without installing it, so that you can be sure whether Ubuntu is working properly on your system or not and are drivers available or not.
2. And if you love Gnome 3, you can use it on Ubuntu instead of default Unity Desktop, you just have to download and install it.
3. Yes there are differences in performance, installing Ubuntu as separate OS is good in performance as compared to if you install Ubuntu as an application in windows 7 through wubi installer.